# Lagrange polynomial: Unexpected interpolation results

Tags: math, interpolation, discrete-mathematics, polynomials

I am trying to interpolate a series of data points using 2nd lagrange polinomial.
having

```
point1:(5;100)
point2: (9;17)
point3: (12;17)
```

and the formula

```
y=(x-x2)*(x-x3)/(x1-x2)*(x1-x3)*y1+
  (x-x1)*(x-x3)/(x2-x1)*(x2-x3)*y2+
  (x-x1)*(x-x2)/(x3-x1)*(x3-x2)*y3
```

It is obvious that a quadratic function might not fit the data.. It is just an example.

But i wonder why the value is surprisingly high for `x=7`.
If i am not wrong its `y=1500`.

Is the above formula correct?

Comment: In your example two points have the same x coordinate. Is this a typo?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: It is about interpolation of DATA. Then tell me how to interpolate a time series? On a piece of paper? Surely it IS a programming question. And not as abstract to put it on math. IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**answer:**

In summary:

1. For the same `x`, you can't have two different `y` values; this violates the definition of a function.
2. you are missing brackets in your formula! Not `(x-x2)*(x-x3)/(x1-x2)*(x1-x3)`, but `((x-x2)*(x-x3)) / ((x1-x2)*(x1-x3))`.
3. back to 1>, note that the interpolation formula has `x3-x2` in the denominator. If you have tied values, you will be dividing 0.
4. How can you make interpolation on such small data set? Yet you are asking for a quadratic interpolation!

---

**follow-up:**

> 1) fixed it. Accidentally i switched all the x and y values. So the points were in format (y,x).

Ah, haha, no wonder.

> 2) Thank you! The brackets improved the approximation. Regarding the missing brackets: I got the formula from the accepted answer here: [Best way to find Quadratic Regression Curve in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2075072/4891738), but I don't understand this rule.

This is the famous, yet fundamental interpolation: Lagrange interpolation. You can verify its formula at [Wolfram mathworld: Lagrange Interpolating Polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html). I don't give you wikipedia link because this one looks more beautiful.

The link you found must contain a typo. Since you have suggest an edit to fix that, hopefully it will soon get approved.

> 3) It is a (significant larger (which answers your 4th question) time series. So it is impossible to have tied values.

Yes, time series won't have tied values.

Answer (score 1):

formula should be correct.but when x=17,you have two different y value,it's might the cause of the trouble.you can try change anthor x.

Comment: With y-values up to 50 the third point does not seem to influence the y value at 7. y-values larger than 50 seem to influence values at x=7 proportional (y_3-=5-->y-=5) maybe that is is the nature of lagrange polynomials 2nd degree